# Underscore characters disappears on jEdit

Tags: python, jedit

I'm using jEdit 4.3 pre 16. As I've mentioned on the title, when I'm typing, sometimes underscore characters disappears. I tried to change fonts, line highlighting etc. but it didn't work.

For example when you type:

```
if __name__ == 'main':
```

it displays:

```
if   name  == 'main':
```

When you click on **name**, it displays the underscores again.

Is there any solution of this problem?

Comment: When I changed the font to "Courier 10 Pitch 14 Plain" it works. Which means I cannot use any other font.

Comment: This question belongs on SuperUser.com .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some editors let you control the linespacing independently of the font size.  If jEdit gives you that control, increase the linespacing just a little.  The problem is that the editor doesn't realize how far below the baseline the underscores extend, and they are being overwritten with the line below.

Comment: Do you know how to do that on jEdit?

Comment: There is an open ticket concerning this problem: http://sourceforge.net/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=2844750&group_id=588&atid=300588.

Comment: I cannot believe that! It is version 4.3.1! They cannot even display the underscores...